# In an <apex:repeat>, receiving error "Content cannot be displayed: Map key section not found in map"

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to iterate over the object inside array, What I want to do is to iterate over the array and it's object and print value of inside object's key.

Below is my code:

```
<ul class="mainDataList">
    <apex:variable var="count" value="{!0}"/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!activity['extra']}" var="x">
        <li>
            <p class="eventTitle">{!activity['extra'][count]['title']}</p>
            <p class="analyticSection">
                <strong> 
                    <apex:outputText value="{! IF((activity['extra'][count]['section'] == null), 'NA',  activity['extra'][count]['section']) }" /> 
                </strong>
            </p>
            <div class="thumbAndEvents">
            </div> 
        </li>
        <apex:variable value="{!count+1}" var="count"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</ui>
```

I am getting "Content cannot be displayed: Map key section not found in map"

If it is null/empty then don't print anything else print the value which is an inside object.

**EDIT:**
Apex Response Model:

```
public SObject extra { get; set; } 


public static Object parse(String input)
    {    
        return  JSON.deserializeUntyped(input);
    }
```

I have specified `extra` key as a sobject and method return value as `Object`.
I had to change it because I have inconsistent data in that perticular key and by doing this way I am able to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: Can you add your apex controller as well

Comment: What is `activity`? And `extra` can't be used as the `value` of a repeat tag if it's represented as a single SObject in the controller. In the sample data in your comment below, it looks like it's an array/list of objects with multiple attributes.

Comment: the 'activity' has lots of key-value pair data but I am facing problem in just 'extra' key which has inconsistent data

Comment: The Apex snippet doesn't show what the `extra` SObject is being populated with. While `repeat` can take any Object, it is usually used to iterate over an Apex collection, like a Map or Set.

Comment: Is it possible the way I am doing?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `<apex:variable>` in that way. From [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_variable.htm):

> **Note:** `<apex:variable>` does not support reassignment inside of an
>   iteration component, such as `<apex:dataTable>` or `<apex:repeat>`. The
>   result of doing so, e.g., incrementing the `<apex:variable>` as a
>   counter, is unsupported and undefined.

As Lokesh said, a snippet of your controller, or at least a clear explanation of the data structure you're trying to iterate over, is needed to give you much additional guidance. But you've defined the `<apex:repeat>`'s `var` as `x`, but then do not make any reference to `x` inside of the `<apex:repeat>`. It seems like the display lines inside the repeat should probably look something like:

```
<p class="eventTitle">{!x['title']}</p>
<p class="analyticSection">
<strong><apex:outputText value="{!IF((x['section'] == null),'NA',
         x['section']) }" /> </strong>
```

But we'd need to know more about the data structure in `activity` to say more.

Comment: I have below type of data to iterate:

extra:[ {duration=, title=New presentation started, section=, hasrating=-1, thumb=null, extra=null}{duration=28, title=Surveys, section=null, hasrating=-1, thumb=null, extra=null} ]

Comment: I want to iterate over the extra array and get each objects' value

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information there, so that other answerers can see it. Please also specify the Apex collection type & what the elements' data types are. But probably you want `{!x.title}` and `{!x.section}`

Comment: It is not working I have tried it

Comment: That's why both Lokesh and I asked you to edit your question (rather than adding another comment) to specify the details of the data structure in the controller.

Comment: I have edited question with details

Comment: I changed as you suggested but it is not working. It is giving the same error